# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’: object ‘relocate’ is not exported by 'namespace:dplyr'

Tags: r, tidyverse

I installed tidyverse using this command:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

But after installing when I call the library with:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I get this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’: object ‘relocate’ is not exported by 'namespace:dplyr'
```

I am trying to do this simple thing:

```
a = 1:100
tibble(a, b = 2 * a)
```

But that gives me this error message:

```
Error in tibble(a, b = 2 * a) : could not find function "tibble"
```

I tried to install again using:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyverse")
```

This is too slow. It never finished installing.
Am I missing something in installing process? Please help.

Comment: Try restarting R,  `install.packages("dplyr")` and copy the full output in your question.

Comment: I'd guess you have old versions of some packages.  Try `update.packages(ask = FALSE)`.

Comment: Make sure that another R process/session that has the package loaded isn't running at the same time you're trying to reinstall the same package.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: when calling `library(bibliometrix)`, it threw a similar error (just not the same package, and not the same object that was "not exported" by dplyr).

I updated all packages with `update.packages(ask = FALSE)`, as suggested by @user2554330. After that, it still wasn't working, so I restarted Rstudio, and that solved the problem, apparently.