# unable to install ggraph package in r

Tags: r

I was trying to install ggraph but is faced with this error. May i know how can i overcome this error? I updated ggplot to 3.0.0 but still the error persists.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggraph':
 object 'nest_legacy' is not exported by 'namespace:tidyr'
Traceback:

1. library(ggraph)
2. tryCatch({
 .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
 .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

Comment: maybe try the solutions here: (I'd also suggest googling your error message;) https://stackoverflow.com/q/65265406/7941188

Comment: Perhaps try updating tidyr with `install.packages("tidyr")`?